# Variable inside link-to template in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a variable in my controller called `appName` that i am calling from URL. The format for URL is `/:appName/configure`. I am using `{{#link-to}}` tag to redirect in the nav.
My question is now do i pass the `appName` inside `link-to`. The current code that i have is

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard' 'testApp' tagName="li" class="uk-active"}}<a nohref>Dashboard</a>{{/link-to}}
```

Here i should be able to change the `testApp` with the variable in from controller. Also if i am doing this wrong would appreciate the correct way to do the same.

Comment: You could make a small use case example: https://ember-twiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can include controller properties in link-to helper.

```
{{#link-to 'dashboard' appName tagName="li" class="uk-active"}}<a nohref>Dashboard</a>{{/link-to}}
```

You should include dynamic segment property name in router.js

```
this.route('dashboard',{path:'/dashboard/:appName/configure'});
```

You can modify the path as your required pattern.

Refer ember guide for dynamic segments:     https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments